# Residual LSTM model building, getting syntax error

Tags: python, numpy, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

```
X_train = np.reshape(X_train, (X_train.shape[0], 1, X_train.shape[1]))
X_test = np.reshape(X_test, (X_test.shape[0], 1, X_test.shape[1]))
```

Trying to train my dataset on the Residual(skip connections) LSTM model via wrapper class:

```
import tensorflow as tf
class ResidualWrapper(tf.keras.Model):
def __init__(self, model):
    super().__init__()
    self.model = model

def call(self, inputs, *args, **kwargs):
    delta = self.model(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
```

The prediction for each timestep is the input from the previous time step plus the delta calculated by the model.

```
return inputs + delta


residual_lstm = ResidualWrapper(
model = Sequential()
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(64,input_shape=(X_train.shape[1], X_train.shape[2]))))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam'))
history = model.fit(X_train, Y_train, epochs=10, batch_size=64, validation_data=(X_test, Y_test), 
                    callbacks=[EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=10)], verbose=1, shuffle=False)
model.summary()
```

#But getting invalid syntax error at model.add(Bidirectional())

Comment: `residual_lstm = ResidualWrapper(`? What is it wrapping?

Comment: You can check Residual Wrapper in : https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/time_series

Comment: I meant that this is the invalid syntax: `ResidualWrapper(model = Sequential() model.add(...`. You should use it like `ResidualWrapper(model)`

Answer (score 0):

To sum up the issue, Keras' Sequential model doesn't support non-linear topology, like the architecture you're trying to achieve here. What you could do instead would be to rewrite the code using Keras' Functional API instead. The reason is because model.Sequential() is meant to strictly only allow layers to be built one by one, or well, sequentially, and with residual connections you are making an additional connection to the beginning of the block.
More details are in the Keras guide: https://keras.io/guides/functional_api/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30210173)